# Get and remove an arbitrary element from a mutable HashSet in Scala

Tags: scala, set, hashset

How do you get and remove an arbitrary element from a mutable HashSet in Scala (similar to python set pop method)? Also what would be the performance of the api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For extracting and removing elements in undefined order from a mutable hash set, try a combination of `head` and `-=` (remove):

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet

def pop[A](hs: HashSet[A]): A = {
  val a = hs.head
  hs -= a
  a
}

val example = HashSet.empty[Int] ++ (0 to 9)

while (!example.isEmpty) {
  val p = pop(example)
  println("Pop element: " + p)
}
```

I'm not sure whether it's caching any keys or hashes internally, but afaik it's either just `O(1)` or amortized `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

@Andrey's answer above should suffice to answer your question as he said 
you can use `.head` function to pop an element.

Here are some more details.

`Sets` are one of the collection libraries of Scala which provide both mutable and immutable methods. If you want specific element to be removed from `Sets` then there is `-` and `+` methods. `-` method is used for removing an element from a `Set` and a new `Set` is returned. Similarly `+` method is used for adding an element in a `Set` which also returns a new `Set` with the element added. So you can write *pop* and *set* functions that will remove and add specific elements.

```
def popFromSet[T](set: Set[T], stringToPop: T) = {
  set - stringToPop
}

def setToSet[T](set: Set[T], stringToPop: T) = {
  set + stringToPop
}
```

And you can use them as

```
popFromSet(stringSet, "second")
setToSet(popFromSet(stringSet, "second"), "second2") 
popFromSet(intSet, 2)
....
```

**List way**

You can do the above `Set` to `List`

If you have a `HashSet` as

```
Set("first", "second", "third")
```

You can get the *second* element popped out by doing

```
val hashList = hashSet.toList
hashList(hashList.indexOf("second"))
```

and if you want to remove the *second* element from the `HashSet` then

```
hashSet - hashList(hashList.indexOf("second"))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: I edited the question in order to clarify what I meant by pop.

Comment: @x89a10, Yes now I understood. Thanks for clarifying. Andrey's answer is good enough to answer your question. I have updated some more information for you help though :) Thanks